# Upgraded to 0.6.13 and now node can't find module moment

Tags: scala.js

I have a Play project that uses scala.js.  Tests all ran fine until I upgraded the scala.js plugin to 0.6.13.  Now I get "Error: Cannot find module '../moment'".

I read on the 0.6.13 release notes that run and test now use node.js by default; I'm sure that change is the root of my problem.

I see the note to install jsdom using "npm install jsdom" either locally or globally.  I first tried installing the moment library globally (npm install -g moment).  No change, so I tried installing in the project's root directory.  Still no change.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the moment.js facade from "io.github.widok" %%% "scala-js-momentjs" % "0.2.0" to "ru.pavkin" %%% "scala-js-momentjs" % "0.4.1".  Changed relevant import statements and recompiled.  Tests passed.

Removed the node_modules directory from the app's root directory.  Tests failed with the earlier error.  Reinstalled the moment library (npm install moment) and tests pass again.